# Post body text occupying featured image space before it loads

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent my posts body text to occupy my featured images space before it gets loaded.

When I go to some post the post content is right bellow my post title until my featured image shows. When it shows the post content jumps down right bellow it. It looks very odd and I am wondering what is the best way to "save" the image space until it gets loaded preventing the post text to occupy its place until its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can set post featured image space with css.

like this:

```
img.featured_image{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Humm.. don't think this is what I am looking for. I'll keep searching. Thanks anyway